# Typescript Rest API POST call with JSON parameter

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to find a code example to send a `POST` request to a `REST` Api with a `JSON` as parameter and get the response and any exceptions / error codes  in Typescript.

Comment: I suggest you check the official documentation, which you should do anyway if you're working with Angular: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start with something like that

**Service**

```
export class MyService{
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

   getSomethingFromServer():Observable<any>{
       return this.httpClient.get('you_request_url');
   }
}
```

**Component**

```
constructor(
    private myService: MyService) {
  }

  this.myService.getSomethingFromServer().subscribe(response => {
     // do whatever you want with the response
  }, error => {
     // handle error here
     // error.status to get the error code
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

First set the headers as follows, the "userIdAuthToken" should be the token returned from security service

```
this.httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.userIdAuthToken
  })
};
```

Then make your request,

```
private _http: HttpClient      // goes in constructor

let saveRequest = this._http.post<Project>(
  this.apiUrl + '/project' + '/post',
  JSON.stringify(data),
  this.httpOptions);
```

saveRequest will be an observable so you need to subscribe to it in your component

Answer (score 2):

//Final working code. You should maintain **service** for api call and call it from Component.ts

```
public post(a : string, data: string): Observable<any>{

    const options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: this.getAuthorizedHeaders(),
      responseType: ResponseContentType.Json,
      withCredentials: false
    });

    return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL, JSON.stringify({ var: a, data: data}), options)
      .map(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: RequestOptions is deprecated. You should use @angular/common/http instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is a library will do the trick? Worth taking a look at `node-fetch`, `fetch-as`, `make-fetch-happen`, and what not.