# How to consume REST with GET and POST

Tags: rest, typescript, post, get

Is there a standard out-of-the-box way to access an API using GET or POST in TypeScript?

I only find libaries that do that like `fetch` or `superagent` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510640/how-to-make-a-rest-post-call-from-reactjs-code) when using React or `HttpClient` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000930/typescript-rest-api-post-call-with-json-parameter) when using React.

I wonder though if there is a plain an simple way from within TypeScript to consume a REST API.

Comment: `fetch` linked above is a built-in in most modern browsers and doesn't require any external libraries. If you're writing JS for the browser it probably *is* the most plain and simple way to consume a REST API.

Also note that there's nothing specific here re: TypeScript, as TS only provides typing, not runtime behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder though if there is a plain an simple way from within TypeScript to consume a REST API.

Lets simplify `REST API` to be *I want to make `GET` and `POST` requests. The fact that it is a `REST` *style* API is not relevant.

> I want to make `GET` and `POST` requests

Native ways of doing this depends on the JavaScript environment. e.g. Browser's traditional API has been `XMLHttpRqeuest` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest which is *fully* supported by TypeScript. A newer API is `fetch` which is *also* supported by TypeScript but *might not be supported* by the browser you are targetting.

On node you would use `http` module https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

## Suggestion

Now if you *want* an API that works across both node and old browsers you will need some library that abstracts the native features. One suggestion is axios which works with  TypeScript out of the box.

Comment: Also try `isomorphic-fetch` which uses the browsers fetch or `node-fetch` when on the server.